# Incrementing and padding in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an app that allows a user to increment a series of numbers. When I `let i = 1`, all is well and my sequence output is perfect. Unfortunately, the series will rarely start with 1, it will start with a user defined number. And that's where I'm getting hung up:

```js
const totalEl = document.querySelector('#total');
const perEl = document.querySelector('#per');
const numEl = document.querySelector('#num');
const calculateEl = document.querySelector('#calculate');
const outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');

calculateEl.addEventListener('click', onCalculateButtonClick);

function onCalculateButtonClick() {
  const total = Number(totalEl.value);
  const numPerRoll = Number(perEl.value);
  const num = Number(numEl.value);
  const numPerBatch = numPerRoll * 2;


  const batches = Math.ceil(total / numPerBatch);
  let output = `Total batches: ${batches}\nTotal rolls: ${batches * 2}\n\n`;

  for (let i = 1; i <= batches; i++) {
    output += `Batch ${i}A -- ${(numPerBatch * (i - 1)) + 1}-${(numPerBatch * (i - 1)) + numPerRoll}\n`;
    output += `Batch ${i}B -- ${(numPerBatch * (i - 1)) + numPerRoll + 1}-${numPerBatch * i}\n`;
  }

  outputEl.innerText = output;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, azure, #a4ffff);
  color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  }
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;"> Generator 0.1 </h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">Please enter your values in the dashboard<br> Note: in order to print a complete 2-up batch, the order may be rounded up</p>

<div><label>Order total <input id="total" value="50000"/></label></div>
<div><label>Total per sequence <input id="per" value="1500"/></label></div>
<div><label>Starting number <input id="num" value="1"/></label></div>
<div><label>Prefix <input id="prefix" value="ABC"/></label></div>

<div><button id="calculate">Calculate</button></div>

<br/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

How do I `let i = a` user defined number? I'm missing something fundamentally obvious here.

I also need to turn this number into a string (I think) and pad it out to 8 digits... I've tried adding something like this in with lots of hilarity, hair pulling and no results:

```
let num = i;
let text = num.toString();
let padded = text.padStart(8,"0");
```

I think what I tried was something like this:

```
for (let i = num; i <= batches; text = num.toString(); padded = text.padStart(8,"0"); {
```

I've got a kind of working version of this at codepen:
https://codepen.io/swartzfeger/pen/yLjgEpK

##### More in-depth dump of what I'm trying to accomplish

**TL;DR** What I need: generate a series of UPC codes that are incremented and split into batches.

Let's say our customer wants 10,000 UPCs, with 1000 UPCs per roll (these are being printed on film and wound onto rolls).

That would be a total of 10 rolls. But each 2x 1000 sequence can be printed at once, printing 2 up. So there are a total of 5 print batches.

That's not the hard part since the example is cut and dried. Most client jobs vary greatly, and we often have to print extra so we're not wasting film -- ie, we always want a full batch and not printing just 1 up for the batch. A partial batch would leave us with 1 roll of empty non-printed film.

ie, an order of 50,000 total, 1500 per sequence. 50k / 3000 per batch leaves us with 16.66 batches. So we would want to round that up to 17. So we would want to bump the print total to 51k (17 x 3000 = 51,000.

What I need to do is create a dashboard where the operator enters the job total (50,000) and the total per sequence (1500). The dashboard would then spit out you're running a job total of 51,000, 17 batches/34 rolls total. It would then give the operator the print breakdown --

- Batch 1A -- 0000-1500
- Batch 1B -- 1501-3000
- Batch 2A -- 3001-4500
- Batch 2B -- 4501-6000 etc

HOWEVER -- we would rarely begin a sequence with i =1 -- we would be picking up from where our last job ended, so the user would enter the new beginning sequence number. So I wouldn't be incrementing from 0 or 1, but an arbitrary number like 6293.

AND -- these numbers are of going to be a fixed length (usually 8 digits). So a starting sequence number of 6293 would have to be padded out to 00006293.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is here.

Comment: can you explain what the code is trying to achieve? from what you have said so far a simple validation might be needed for `user Input` regarding numbers, other than that,  it is kinda sorta blurry.

Comment: "*How do I let `i` [equal] a user-defined number?*" - the same way you're assigning the other user-defined numbers to variables. While I've just converted your posted code into a working (reproduces your problem, whatever that might be) snippet in your question in future please do this yourself (off-site demos are lovely, but the code must be here in your question). Also, `place-items: left;` is an invalid declaration (`left` is an invalid value), and `display: grid-auto-rows` is similarly invalid, but presumably you meant `display: grid`?

Comment: Need to generate a series of UPC codes, incremented and split into batches. 
 
ie, order of 50k total, 1500 per sequence. 50k / 3k per batch (printing 2 up) leaves us with 16.66 batches. So we want to round that up to 17. Now bump the print total to 51k (17 x 3000 = 51,000). 
 
I need to create a dashboard where the user enters the job total (50k) and the total per sequence (1500). The dashboard would then spit out a running job total of 51,000, 17 batches/34 rolls total. It would then give the user the print breakdown -- 

Batch 1A -- 0000-1500  
Batch 1B -- 1501-3000  
etc

Comment: Apologies for the offsite code and yes, I'm an idiot with CSS and should've taken that out. Mea culpa.

Comment: No worries, you're new and it does take a bit of time to familiarise around here. With that in mind, though, would you please [edit] that explanation into the question itself, since comments are transitory and those answering don't always read through the comments to find the details (and, really, they shouldn't have to). Remember, we know *nothing* of what you're doing except what's in the question, so explaining the requirements, steps and purpose, like we're 5 is - honestly - a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a small utility function like so:

```
const z = (number, size) => number.toString().padStart(size, "0");
```

Then assign some variables to the function's returns and then interpolate those variables into the template literals like so:

```
let A1 = z(AB, 8);
let A2 = z(AB + (now / 2) - 1, 8);
let B1 = z(AB + (now / 2), 8);
let B2 = z(AB + now - 1, 8);
output += `Batch ${z(i + 1, 2)}A -- ${A1}-${A2}\n`;
output += `Batch ${z(i + 1, 2)}B -- ${B1}-${B2}\n`;
```

I removed the `for` loop and added `.reduce()`.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const genForm = document.forms.generator;
const fc = genForm.elements;
const totalFC = fc.total;
const perFC = fc.per;
const numFC = fc.num;
const outputFC = fc.output;

// Utility function for padding zeros
const z = (number, size) => number.toString().padStart(size, "0");

genForm.addEventListener('submit', onCalculate);

function onCalculate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const total = Number(totalFC.value);
  const numPerRoll = Number(perFC.value);
  const init = Number(numFC.value);
  const numPerBatch = numPerRoll * 2;

  const batches = Math.ceil(total / numPerBatch);
  let output = `Total batches: ${batches}\nTotal rolls: ${batches*2}\n\n`;

  // Generate an array of batches
  const totalBatches = [...new Array(batches)].fill(numPerBatch);
  /**
   * On each iteration of totalBatches by .reduce()...
   * >AB< is the accumulator, it will keep track of it's own value
   * >now< is the current value (>numPerBatch<)
   * >AB< starts as >init<, defaulting to 1
   * >A1< - >A2< is >numPerRoll<
   * >B1< - >B2< is >numPerRoll<
   * >output< is rendered to display ranges A and B
   * >now< is added to >AB<
   * The returned value isn't used but needs to be defined so
   * that the accumulator returns on the next iteration increased
   */
  const final = totalBatches.reduce((AB, now, idx) => {
    let A1 = z(AB, 8);
    let A2 = z(AB + (now / 2) - 1, 8);
    let B1 = z(AB + (now / 2), 8);
    let B2 = z(AB + now - 1, 8);
    output += `Batch ${z(idx + 1, 2)}A -- ${A1}-${A2}\n`;
    output += `Batch ${z(idx + 1, 2)}B -- ${B1}-${B2}\n`;
    return AB + now;
  }, init);

  outputFC.innerText = output;
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.15 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, azure, #a4ffff);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  width: min(70vw, 500px);
}

input,
button {
  font: inherit;
}

input {
  width: 12rem;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 20px 15px 0;
}

label sup {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

legend b,
[type="number"],
output {
  font-family: Consolas;
}

[type="number"] {
  text-align: right;
}

.note {
  margin-left: 0.5ch;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-indent: -1ch;
}

sup {
  color: tomato
}
```

```html
<form id="generator">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><b>❚❘❘❙⦀</b>Generator <b>0.1❚⦀⦀∥❙❙❘❘❘⦀∥</b></legend>
    <p>Please enter your values in the dashboard</p>
    <label><span>Order total<sup>⚝</sup></span> <input id="total" type="number" value="50000"/>
 </label>
    <label>Total per sequence <input id="per" type="number" value="1500"/></label>
    <label>Starting number <input id="num" type="number" value="1"/></label>
    <label>Prefix <input id="prefix" placeholder="ABC"/></label>

    <button>Calculate</button>
    <p class='note'><sup>⚝</sup>Note: in order to print a complete 2-up batch, <br>the order may be rounded up.</p>
    <output id="output"></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect but not quite right, due to my poor explanation --

The Batch 01A, 01B can start at a fixed value of 1 and simply increment... it's the UPC series that uses the user defined num.

So a user defined num of 3 should start off as 00000003-00001502. But above in your example it starts off 00006001. I'm still trying to parse that to figure out why.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks so much for your utility function, it's so close!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I padded the batch numbers so the whole thing looks even and straight. ex. Batch 01A. It's probably this part of the expressions: `* (i - 1))` that's the problem.

Comment: Ok I see that now, the padding isn't the problem and looks nice. The issue is that the  Batch 01A, 01B etc doesn't need to be i, 2 or be user defined. I can simply start at 1 and then ++. The user is defining the beginning number of the actual UPC sequence, so if num = 123 (with the padding), the sequence would begin 00000123 + (numberPerRoll -1).

Comment: @Ringthane IC, ok see update.

Comment: that is perfect, and your //** commenting helped VERY much! 

There is only one small issue... why do the batches start with '00' and not '01'? I didn't see a //comment about idx so I'm not sure if that could be causing it.

Comment: Fixed it by adding +1 to `idx` it's because all arrays normally begin at 0. I also streamlined the code and added a little styling zazz. There was nothing wrong with your code, I was just bored.

Comment: that is ABSOLUTELY PERFECT! I concatenated the prefix to the upc for the final icing so I did ${prefix} ${A1} - ${prefix} ${A2} so the "correct" upc could be displayed for the user. Thank you so much. And had I studied further I would've known arrays start at 0. Good stuff thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The const z utility @zer00ne added cleaned things up for padding the digits

```
const z = (number, size) => number.toString().padStart(size, "0");
```

The user defined number sets the starting number of the sequence, and size determines the length in digits of the sequence. The "0" determines what the sequence will be padded with to reach the required final length.

ex, the user defines '123' as the starting the number of the sequence; const z turns this into '00000123' (an 8-digit sequence)

Defining the value >now< for the accumulator/iteration made things work flawlessly.

By using AB + now, the batches were able to increment properly:

```
// Generate an array of batches

const totalBatches = [...new Array(batches)].fill(numPerBatch);

// * On each iteration of totalBatches by .reduce()...
// * >AB< is the accumulator, it will keep track of it's own value
// * >now< is the current value (>numPerBatch<)
// * >AB< starts as >init<, defaulting to 1
// * >A1< - >A2< is >numPerRoll<
// * >B1< - >B2< is >numPerRoll<
// * >output< is rendered to display ranges A and B
// * >now< is added to >AB<
// * The returned value isn't used but needs to be defined so
// * that the accumulator returns on the next iteration increased

const final = totalBatches.reduce((AB, now, idx) => {
let A1 = z(AB, 8);
let A2 = z(AB + now / 2 - 1, 8);
let B1 = z(AB + now / 2, 8);
let B2 = z(AB + now - 1, 8);
```

and for the final output:

```
output += `Batch ${z(idx + 1, 2)}A | ${prefix} ${A1} - ${prefix} ${A2}\n`;
output += `Batch ${z(idx + 1, 2)}B | ${prefix} ${B1} - ${prefix} ${B2}\n`;
return AB + now;
}, init);

outputEl.innerText = output;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).